# Different menu in master.page depending on login type

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, master-pages

I have 2 types of users (phonebookers and salesrep). They are supposed to have 2 different menu bars, pending on their login.

From the login.aspx - I set a number of `Session[]`s among them an `["EmployeeType"]`.
In my master page I have a `ContentPlaceholder ID="Menu"`.

Master.page seems locked in place, long before I can change anything pending some Session value. I found the load sequence which seems to confirm my suspession as Masterpage is loaded and locked way before any contentpage get in play.

I tried `<% If (Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() == "1") { %> type 1 employee <% } else {%>Type 2 employee<% } %>` - without luck.

I tried doing it in `Page_PreRender(EventArgs e)` - no luck.
I tried having the hyperlink controls in the masterpage, without a text and then setting the text later i PreRender and visible = true/false - no luck.

Google says there is an option with javascript but I haven't found any examples or I haven't recognised any javascript as something I could use.

Google found a fair few people having the opposite problem of mine, their masterpage loads way too many times and they want to stop it doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  <% If (Session["EmployeeType"].ToString()  == "1") { %> type 1 employee <% } else {%>Type 2 employee<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to re^n-review my code. Spotting I have 2 types of employees - type 2 and type 1/0. For some reason one of the types have both 0 and 1s.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid doing logic in your masterpage, it tends to get a bit messy.

What I would do is to create two panels and hide one of them by default, the one that is least common to be shown. And then Enable the appropriet panel from your masterpage code behind like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <asp:Panel ID="UserMenu" runat="server">
        <MenuControl:UserMenu />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="AdminMenu" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <MenuControl:AdminMenu />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The `Page_Load` method looks like this now:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["EmployeeType"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        AdminMenu.Visible = true;
        UserMenu.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        AdminMenu.Visible = false;
        UserMenu.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

This will show my User Control `AdminMenu` if it is an Employee with `EmployeeType` equal to  1 and otherwise show the `UserMenu` User Control.

Comment: This way you are doing logic in your master page, contrary to your first sentence.

Comment: @nima, in my first sentance I am talking about the `Master Page Design File`, doing logic code-behind is not bad imho.

Comment: So you mean you put the panels on all of the pages that need a menu? If so, what if you want to change something in the menu.

Comment: No, I put the panels inside MasterPage.master, and the Logic in the Page_Load of your MasterPage.Master.cs. And the menus imho should be UserControls if they have a lot of content, that way, they don't mess up your master page.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend defining some public static methods in the master page class to set different types of menu:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    // ...

    public static void SetEmployeeMenu(MasterPage master)
    {
        // do whatever you want on master page
        ((SiteMaster)master).EmployeeMenu.Style.Add("display", "");
    }
}
```

And then on your content page load event decide which menu you want to display and use these functions:

```
SiteMaster.SetEmployeeMenu(this.Master);
```